# MKWebView upgrade

Tags: ionic-framework

I've built and installed an Ionic native app and trying to run it.
While running the application i get an error in xcode:

> 2018-03-01 15:17:42.748572+0200 StorSenseMobile[8770:959523] API
>   error: <_UIKBCompatInputView: 0x7fc2f750a7e0; frame = (0 0; 0 0);
>   layer = > returned 0 width, assuming
>   UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric
>
> 2018-03-01 15:17:42.748731+0200
>   StorSenseMobile[8770:959523] API error: <_UIKBCompatInputView:
>   0x7fc2f750a7e0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = >
>   returned 0 width, assuming UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric

I've checked and some people suggest upgrading to MKWebView.

> Where can i find info regarding upgrading to MKWebview? Is that the
>   correct solution for this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When Apple deprecated UIWebView, it was in favor of WKWebView. WKWebView is the upgrade that is likely being recommended. MKWebView is either a typo or someone's wrapper around WKWebView. You can see instruction on how to upgrade an ionic app [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview#installation-instructions).

That being said. I don't believe that will necessarily solve the issue you are seeing. I saw that same log message when I was running my ionic 1 app on the iPhone X simulator. I still saw the same message after upgrading to WKWebView, so it did not fix the issue for me. After a lot of testing, I was able to fix the issue by delaying execution of the js in my first controller until after the device was ready.

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function(){init();});
```

My theory is that updating the DOM by binding a value to it prior to the device being ready was causing the error. It makes some sense, as if the device isn't ready and returning a width of 0, you aren't ready to render the DOM. This is especially true if you are using the viewport meta tag and setting width to device-width.